# std::shared_ptr and dlopen(), avoiding undefined behavior

Tags: c++11, shared-libraries, shared-ptr, undefined-behavior, dlsym

`dlopen()` is a C function used for dynamically loading shared libraries at runtime. The pattern, in case you're not familiar, is thus:

- Call `dlopen("libpath", flag)` to get a `void *handle` to the library
- Call `dlsym(handle, "object_name")` to get a `void *object` to the thing you want from the library
- Do what you want with `object`
- Call `dlclose (handle)` to unload the library.

This is, in C++, a perfect use-case for the so-called *aliasing constructor* of `std::shared_ptr`. The pattern becomes:

- Construct a `std::shared_ptr<void> handle` from `dlopen("libpath", flag)` that will call `dlclose()` when its destructor is called
- Construct a `std::shared_ptr<void> object` from `handle` and `dlsym(handle, "object_name")`
- Now we can pass `object` wherever we want, and completely forget about `handle`; when `object`'s destructor is called, whenever that happens to be, `dlclose()` will be called automagically

Brilliant pattern, and it works beautifully. One small problem, though. The pattern above requires a cast from `void*` to `whatever_type_object_is*`. If `"object_name"` refers to a function (which most of the time it does, considering the use-case), this is undefined behavior.

In C, there is a hack to get around this. From the `dlopen` man page:

```
// ...
void *handle;    
double (*cosine)(double);
// ...
handle = dlopen("libm.so", RTLD_LAZY);
// ...

/* Writing: cosine = double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
   would seem more natural, but the C99 standard leaves
   casting from "void *" to a function pointer undefined.
   The assignment used below is the POSIX.1-2003 (Technical
   Corrigendum 1) workaround; see the Rationale for the
   POSIX specification of dlsym(). */

*(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");
// ...
```

which obviously works just fine, in C. But is there an easy way to do this with `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: why do you need `std::shared_ptr` to the poointer, returned by dlsym?

Comment: @Slava: to guaranty the lifetime (don't call `dlclose` when there is that pointer).

Comment: The aliasing constructor of `std::shared_ptr` allows two `std::shared_ptr`s to share the same "close condition" (my term, not official) without pointing to the same object or even the same type. Using a `std::shared_ptr` for the value returned by `dlsym()` gains me this benefit: the lifetime of the library is tied to the lifetime of `object`.

Comment: You ask if you could do the C way to get the pointer (before using it for the `shared_ptr`) ?

Comment: Then just create a structure with pointer to function and `std::shared_ptr` to library handle and have `std::shared_ptr` to that structure. You may loose coolness of using "close condition" but that should work.

Comment: While C leaves it undefined, doesn't the writer of `dlopen` provide any guarantees about what happens?  I guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The pattern above requires a cast from void* to whatever_type_object_is*. If "object_name" refers to a function (which most of the time it does, considering the use-case), this is undefined behavior.

Well this is not entirely true, at least in C++ it is just conditionally-supported.

**5.2.10.8** says:

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning
>   of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in
>   both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cvqualification,
>   shall yield the original pointer value.

So assuming that what `dlsym` does internally is casting a function pointer to a `void*`, I believe that you are ok if you just cast it back to a function pointer.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast In particular point 8 covers this

Comment: And I do think this was the intent http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#195

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
struct dlib
{
public:
  template<class T>
  std::shared_ptr<T> sym(const char* name) const {
    if (!handle) return {};
    void* sym = dlsym(handle->get(), name);
    if (!sym) return {};
    return {reinterpret_cast<T*>(sym), handle};
  }
  // returns a smart pointer pointing at a function for name:
  template<class Sig>
  std::shared_ptr<Sig*> pfunc(const char* name) const {
    if (!handle) return {};
    void* sym = dlsym(handle->get(), name);
    if (!sym) return {};
    Sig* ret = 0;
    // apparently approved hack to convert void* to function pointer
    // in some silly compilers:
    *reinterpret_cast<void**>(&ret) = sym;
    return {ret, handle};
  }
  // returns a std::function<Sig> for a name:
  template<class Sig>
  std::function<Sig> function(const char* name) const {
    // shared pointer to a function pointer:
    auto pf = pfunc(name);
    if (!pf) return {};
    return [pf=std::move(pf)](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
      return (*pf)(decltype(args)(args)...);
    };
  }
  dlib() = default;
  dlib(dlib const&)=default;
  dlib(dlib &&)=default;
  dlib& operator=(dlib const&)=default;
  dlib& operator=(dlib &&)=default;

  dlib(const char* name, int flag) {
    void* h = dlopen(name, flag);
    if (h)
    {
      // set handle to cleanup the dlopen:
      handle=std::shared_ptr<void>(
        h,
        [](void* handle){
          int r = dlclose(handle);
          ASSERT(r==0);
        }
      );
    }
  }
  explicit operator bool() const { return (bool)handle; }
private:
  std::shared_ptr<void> handle;
};
```

I doubt that hack is needed.  As @sbabbi noted, the round-trip to `void*` is conditionally supported.  On a system using `dlsym` to return function pointers, it better be supported.

Comment: You don't inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. I think that you swap order of `shared_ptr` arguments (for the *aliasing* constructor).

Comment: @Jarod42 oops, earlier version did.  Turned out storing a `handle` was smarter.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a struct to have your pointer to function and handle to library:

```
template<typename T>
struct dlsymbol {
   dlsymbol( const std::string &name, std::shared_ptr<void> handle ) :
      m_handle( std::move( handle ) )
   {
       *(void **)(&m_func) = dlsym( handle.get(), name.c_str );
   }

   std::shared_ptr<void> m_handle;
   T *m_func;
};

auto cosine = std::make_shared<dlsymbol<double(double)>>( "cos", handle );
auto d = cosine->m_func( 1.0 );
```

I did not compile it, but I think it is sufficient to show the idea.